# Certificate binary matching

Tags: tls, public-key-infrastructure

Is it an industry practice to do a binary matching of client public certificate when doing SSL with client authentication?
I was thinking that if the client can successfully do the SSL handshake, there is no added security by matching the certificate binary to one that is stored, but I heard some places do an extra layer of check by storing the client certificate and doing a binary matching of the whole certificate.
What is the added security in this?

Comment: It would be great if you have a reference for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are referring to certificate pinning in the context of client authentication, where the server not only checks that the client can successfully establish the SSL handshake with the certificate (which means the client knows the private key) but that the certificate is exactly what the server expects (or one of the expected certificates).

The check that the certificate is exactly the expected is useful if you deal with self-signed certificates or if you want to add an additional protection on top of the existing validation to make sure that no attacker was able to get a certificate for the same subject from a trusted CA. It is typically not done by comparing the whole certificate as binary (although this is possible) but by comparing the fingerprint of the certificate or of the public key inside the certificate. In the latter case this is known as public key pinning.

This technique is more commonly used in the other direction, i.e. to make sure that the server certificate is the expected. This is used in today's browsers to protect important domains like google.com by embedding the expected fingerprint of the public key into the browser. With the HTTP extension [HPKP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Public_Key_Pinning) any other sites can do public key pinning too.

Comment: Hi I'm talking about client authentication, not server authentication.

Comment: @v3ga: This is more or less the same apart from the HPKP part. I've rewrote the answer so that it writes more about your use case.